# Does kubernetes create a pod on one node by default?

Tags: kubernetes

When running `kubectl create -f ./pod.json`, by default, does Kubernetes create this pod on just one node in the cluster or multiple nodes?

Comment: You can't create pods like that with `kubectl`, but you can create one via a deployment (`kubectl create deployment`) in which case yes one pod is created

Comment: @dippynark, sorry about the confusion. I edited the question to clarify what I'm asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `pod.json` contains a pod specification for a single pod then only one pod will be created on one node chosen by the scheduler (assuming pod.spec.nodeName is not set)